# Wide Tile Windows Phone 7.1 using MangoPollo

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

I have a Windows Phone 7.1 app and I want to include a wide iconic tile. I found a library called MangoPollo:

http://mangopollo.codeplex.com/

I found this code within:

```
var tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault();
if (tile != null)
{
    var tileData = new FlipTileData();
    tileData.Title = "Start Debugging";

    tileData.BackContent = "switch to windows phone, we've got candy";
    tileData.BackgroundImage = new Uri("Assets/tileBackground.png", UriKind.Relative);
    tileData.BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("Assets/tileBackBackground.png", UriKind.Relative);

   tileData.WideBackContent = "switch to windows phone, we've got candy";
   tileData.WideBackgroundImage = new Uri("Assets/wideTileBackground.png", UriKind.Relative);
   tileData.WideBackBackgroundImage = new Uri("Assets/wideTileBackBackground.png", UriKind.Relative);

   tile.Update(tileData);
}
```

The problem is there isn't any documentation included on Codeplex for the project so I'm not sure where to insert this code (i.e. which function) to change the tile size from normal to wide.

Comment: Take a look at this [Windows Phone dev blog](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/01/22/windows-phone-7-8-and-windows-phone-8-live-tile-light-up-for-windows-phone-os-7-1-apps.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of creating Wide Tile in Windows Phone 7. Tested it and it works.
Check this out.

http://www.supersmithbros.com/index.php/latest-news/93-how-to-create-a-wp8-wide-tile-in-wp7-xna

Answer (score 0):

You may call it where you want and there is no code to change tile at the user screen, because it's not allowed.

Comment: Call it where we want?.. In the mainpage.xaml.cs or app.xaml.cs?
And this code should be in a  function. If mainpage should i call it in the constructor. If in app.xaml.cs in which method to call it in.
AND BY THE END WILL IT WORK ?

Comment: Will work everywhere. This code have no relationships with your app. This code will also work in the background agent, where no app.xaml.cs and mailpage.xaml.cs. Do not forget to pin the tile of your application before use this code.  Because this code only updates the tile.

Comment: So if the code is run without the tile being pinned will that give a error?

Comment: No, it just do nothing visible, because the main tile always exist (just not displayed). To create a tile (secondary tile, not a main one), you should use Create() and supply uri.

Answer (score 0):

If you [look in the source code](http://mangopollo.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Mangopollo/Mangopollo.Sample/MainPage.xaml.cs), in the link to MangoPollo which you supplied, the sample code places the tile code in a button click event. So what I would do in your app, is make an option to set up this new tile (settings page, maybe?) and when the user turns this setting on, you would run the code in that event handler.

This way, the code doesn't unnecessarily execute multiple times (as it would if it were in the constructor of a page or in app.xaml.cs).

Hope this helps!

**Edit:**

Based on your comment then, maybe you *can* put it in the constructor of your first page. Maybe, then, to prevent the code from executing more than necessary, you could check the existing `tile` to see if it already has a `WideBackgroundImage`, and if it doesn't, then set it and call `Update()` otherwise just continue.

Comment: @Ihan16 Firstly thanks for the edit.
Secondly i want this to be done automatically without going to the settings page.

Comment: Not sure how to do that :(

Comment: Doesnt work some nullreference exception shows up :(
At the first line itself
 `code`var tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault();`code`